# How can I have two view layouts to switch between? (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

So I have this timer app that I am developing, and there is a setting in it to change from minutes:seconds to hours:minutes:seconds. This means that I need to adjust the UI of the app once the setting is changed. Considering I have constraints on the UI already, how could I do this?

When it is set to minutes:seconds, it displays this:
[minutes:seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QgkF.png)

and then when it is set to hours:minutes:seconds, I want the UI to look like this: [hours:minutes:seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gMRj.png)

Basically I would like to know the most efficient way to change the UI of the app when an action occurs. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create two custom classes -

```
MinutesView
HoursView
```

Both will be inheriting from UIView. For each ofttimes classes you need their content which is their subviews. You can do that either programatically or via XIBs. It  doesn't really matter.
Inside these subclasses implement the layout with two or three subviews.

Both classes will also have a time variable. Implement a property observer on both. Once a new time is set, update the labels that represent time digits.

Once you have both working. Put them both into your main scene, lay them out however you wish.

The only thing you will have to do when switching between two modes is set the .hidden property on both. Obviously when one is hidden the other one is not and vice versa.